# What would be java equivalent code for this C# code?

Tags: c#, java

I am not sure how to implement this C# code into java? Dev is class that has this code.

```
    public enum ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap
    {
        Config5VReg = 0x80,
        ConfigPMux  = 0x40, 
    }

   public void SetVReg(bool val)
    {
        //vReg = val;
        if (val)
        {
            configSetupByte0 |= (int)Dev.ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap.Config5VReg;
        }
        else
        {
            configSetupByte0 &= ~(int)Dev.ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap.Config5VReg;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I created enum to fit above enum with an constructor. But in SetVReg method, it says cannot cast ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap.Config5VReg to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enum ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap
{
    Config5VReg(0x80),
    ConfigPMux(0x40); 

    public final int value;

    private ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap(final int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public void SetVReg(boolean val)
{
    //vReg = val;
    if (val)
    {
        configSetupByte0 |= ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap.Config5VReg.value;
    }
    else
    {
        configSetupByte0 &= ~ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap.Config5VReg.value;   
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me possible way to covert this if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AdcChannels), channel)) {....}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# expert, but I think that this is functionality equivalent:

```
public void SetVReg(bool val) {
    if (val) {
        configSetupByte0 |= 0x80;
    } else {
        configSetupByte0 &= ~0x80;   
    }
}
```

The rest is just sugar.

---

> But in SetVReg method, it says cannot cast ConfigSetupByte0Bitmap.Config5VReg to int.

That's right.  In Java, enums are object types, and can't be cast to integers.  If you want a Java enum with an integer "value" you need to do something line this:

```
    public enum Foo {
        ONE(1), THREE(3);
        public final value;
        Foo(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
    System.out.println("THREE is " + THREE.value);
```